# initialize array to 0 in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization

In C this can be done easily by doing

```
int myArray[10] = { 0 }; // all elements 0
```

(taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value?rq=1) answer)

My question is, is there a way similar (or same) in C++ which I can use to initialize the array to 0 in the constructor?

---

**EDIT 1**

I need to do the above using *initialization list*.

May be something like

```
struct aa
{
    int i[10];

    aa() : i {0}{}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how it can be done

```
struct A
{
    A() : a{} {}
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N];
} a;
```

Or

```
struct A
{
    A() : a{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } {}
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N];
} a;

for (int x : a.a) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Another approach is to use an object of type `std::array`. For example

```
#include <array>

//...

struct A
{
    A() 
    { 
        a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; 
    }
    enum { N = 10 };
    std::array<int, N> a;
} a;

for (int x : a.a) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Same syntax applies in C++, although it has a different name (list initialization, or in this case its special case, aggregate initialization).

However, in the member initialization list, you have to use the different syntax: `myArray{}`. Note that explicitly initializing the first element to 0 is unnecessary, since that is the default.